# Delegation between two ViewControllers without segues

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I am learning the concept of delegation and I am stuck in my project. I believe the solution is simple, but as this is something new for me I have no idea what is wrong.

Project concept is simple:
There are two views in the application. In the first view you press the button "change the color" and as a result second view appears. In the second view there are three text fields where user puts numbers respectively for R G and B values in RGB color. When the button is tapped, second view disappears and the first view's background should be changed with color based on the user's input. I assume that the user put correct numbers, therefore at this moment I use forced unwrapping for those values.
At this moment views appear correctly, but the background color of the first view does not change and I have no idea why.

Beneath is the code for two view controllers. I will appreciate any hints.

First VC: ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ColorChangeDelegate {

let secondStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as UIViewController
var secondVC = SecondViewController()


@IBAction func changeColourButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    presentViewController(secondStoryboard, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    secondVC.colorDelegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func didChangeColor(controller: SecondViewController, color: UIColor) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = color
}
```

}

and second VC: SecondViewController.swift

```
 protocol ColorChangeDelegate {
    func didChangeColor(controller: SecondViewController, color: UIColor)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myRTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var myGTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var myBTextField: UITextField!

    var colorDelegate : ColorChangeDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        myRTextField.delegate = self
        myGTextField.delegate = self
        myBTextField.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func goButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        let r = Int(myRTextField.text!)!
        let g = Int(myGTextField.text!)!
        let b = Int(myBTextField.text!)!
        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(r), green: CGFloat(g), blue: CGFloat(b), alpha: 1.0)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        colorDelegate?.didChangeColor(self, color: color)
        presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning your delegate to `secondVC` but the view controller that is actually being presented is in `secondStoryboard`, so you should set the `colorDelegate` property of `secondStoryboard`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, after this change it works as is should.